# Django Rest Framework - AttriubuteError: 'AutoSchema' object has no attribute 'get_link'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The following code is throwing me error when i run (http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

schema_view = get_schema_view(title='Blog API')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include('posts.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),  # Peculiar to rest_framework
    path('api/v1/rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),  # Peculiar to django-rest-auth package
    path('api/v1/rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),  # Peculiar to rest_auth app
    path('docs/', include_docs_urls(title='Blog API')),
    path('schema/', schema_view),
]
```

Here is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'AutoSchema' object has no attribute 'get_link'
```

Please Help suggest a potential solution

Answer (score 2):

add this to your settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  ...
  'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema'
}
```